# Mysql Calculate rank of teams from different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a kind of peddy paper. For that I have the following tables:

**teams**

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creator_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friend_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

**team_log**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `progress_tracker` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `clues_found` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `clues_to_find` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

1. Each team is composed by two users;
2. Each user starts out with a variable number of clues found;
3. clues_found can either increase or decrease. No guarantee that the highest number is the latest;

I need to get a rank of the teams (in percentage) based on the average of the number of clues the user found since they joined (for both users in a team) - clues_found on the row with biggest date minus clues_found on the record with lowest date).

For instance if I have the following data for each table:

**teams table data**

```
+--------+------------+------------+---------------+
|     id | creator_id | friend_id  |   team_name   |
+--------+------------+------------+---------------+
|      1 |         25 |         28 |         Test1 |
|      2 |         31 |          5 |         Test2 |
+--------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

**team_log table data**

```
+--------+---------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+
|     id | user_id | team_id |    date    | clues_found | clues_to_find |
+--------+---------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      1 |      25 |       1 | 2013-01-6  |           3 |            24 |
|      2 |      25 |       1 | 2013-01-8  |           7 |            24 |
|      3 |      25 |       1 | 2013-01-10 |          10 |            24 |
|      4 |      28 |       1 | 2013-01-8  |           5 |            30 |
|      5 |      28 |       1 | 2013-01-14 |          20 |            30 |
|      6 |      31 |       2 | 2013-01-11 |           6 |            14 |
|      7 |       5 |       2 | 2013-01-9  |           2 |            20 |
|      8 |       5 |       2 | 2013-01-10 |          10 |            20 |
|      9 |       5 |       2 | 2013-01-12 |          14 |            20 |
+--------+---------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

**Desired Result**

```
+-------------+---------------------+
|     team_id |   team_percentage   |
+-------------+---------------------+
|           1 |         39,58333333 |
|           2 |         30          |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

As a reference this is an intermediate representation which might help to understand:

```
+-------------+---------+---------------------+
|     user_id | team_id | precentage_per_user |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+
|          25 |       1 | 29,16666667         |
|          28 |       1 | 50                  |
|          31 |       2 | 0                   |
|           5 |       2 | 60                  |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+
```

So far I have the following sql:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      tl2.team_id, (tl2.weight - tl1.weight)*100/tl2.clues_to_find
   from 
       ( select
               team_id,user_id,clues_found
            FROM 
               `team_log` 
            where 1

            group by
               team_id, user_id
            order by
               `date` ) base
       join (select team_id, user_id, clues_found, clues_to_find from `team_log` where user_id = base.user_id and team_id = base.team_id group by team_id, user_id order by `date` desc) tl2
```

But this returns an error as I'm not allowed to use base.user_id inside the second query. I'm also not very sure I'm heading in the right direction.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please add a line break after "team_log table data" title so we can see it properly

Comment: Can you explain this statement:  "I need to get a rank of the teams (in percentage) based on the average of the number of clues the user found since they joined (for both users in a team) - clues_found on the row with biggest date minus clues_found on the record with lowest date)."  When I apply it to team 2, I get -12 -- the total clues found is 32, the average is 8.  Then I subtract 14 and 6.

Comment: @jribeiro That particular line gives an ambiguous impression... :) sorry. You mean average on first and last day clues_found per user per team? It dosen't seem to give a big number like yours.. shown in the expected results..

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well it's per user first because each user has an own goal. So for team 2, user 31: (6 - 6) * 100/14 = 0%. For user 5: (14-2)*100/20=60%

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes. That's correct. Regarding user 31 I got mistaken, the result should be 0% and not 57 as the initial and final values are the same.

Comment: @jribeiro please check on the answer I posted. Sorry for my confusion about your logic, not 100% sure also I posted the answer. So perhaps you can comment after giving it a shot :) Either the data I have taken from your question differs from the ones you have upted.. please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this and comment:

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc5bd/27)

Team pct:

```
select z.team_id, avg(z.pct) as teampct
from (
select x.user_id, y.team_id, x.mndate,
y.mxdate, x.mnclues_found,
y.mxclues_found, 
(((y.mxclues_found - x.mnclues_found)*100)
/y.mxclues_tofind) pct
from 
(select user_id, team_id, min(date) mndate, 
min(clues_found) as mnclues_found
from team_log
group by user_id, team_id) x
left join 
(select user_id, team_id, max(date) mxdate, 
max(clues_found) as mxclues_found, 
 max(clues_to_find) as mxclues_tofind
from team_log
group by user_id, team_id) y
on x.user_id = y.user_id and
x.team_id = y.team_id) z
group by z.team_id
;
```

Results 1:

```
| USER_ID | TEAM_ID |   MNDATE |   MXDATE | MNCLUES_FOUND | MXCLUES_FOUND |     PCT |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       5 |       2 | 13-01-09 | 13-01-12 |             2 |            14 |      60 |
|      25 |       1 | 13-01-06 | 13-01-10 |             3 |            10 | 29.1667 |
|      28 |       1 | 13-01-08 | 13-01-14 |             5 |            20 |      50 |
|      31 |       2 | 13-01-11 | 13-01-11 |             6 |             6 |       0 |
```

Results final:

```
| TEAM_ID |  TEAMPCT |
----------------------
|       1 | 39.58335 |
|       2 |       30 |
```

Comment: I think the different values aren because you're using a wrong formula. Should be something like (maxDateRow.clues_found - minDateRow.clues_found)*100/clues_to_find. But the sqlfiddle is worth the world. ;) Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @jribeiro I am glad you got the answer :) and happy that you used teh sqlfiddle. It's a great question and well articulated +1 for that. I updated with the correct formula. But not able to match the results as per your question though ;) And `explain plan` showed in sqlfiddle would help you to determine the best answer.

Comment: @jribeiro you are absolutely right, there was a formula change to be done. I didn't notice that you are dividing by `max clues to find` ;) Good Luck!

Comment: @jribeiro infact the query can be even shorted. You don't have to use the out query. It can be done within `x` and `y` join itself. Check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc0f6/1 Quite fast as well.

Comment: Great insight. Thanks once again.

Comment: I don't even think this solves the original problem.  You're just taking min/max clues_found without regard to date in this query.

Comment: @ebyrob so the answer came from? I meant the numbers here came from?

Comment: @bonCodigo The test data just happens to have min clues_found on min date rows and max clues_found on max date rows.  Getting the intermediate result this way is as simple as: `select team_id, user_id, (MAX(clues_found) - MIN(clues_found)) / MAX(clues_to_find) as pct from team_log group by team_id, user_id` which also isn't correct.

Comment: @bonCodigo try setting clues_found = 11 where team_log.id = 2 and then compare the results of your query against the other queries here.  Then re-read the rules: "3. clues_found can either increase or decrease. No guarantee that the highest number is the latest"

Answer (score 2):

Here's another query that will produce the correct result:

```
SELECT calc.team_id, AVG((calc.end_clues - calc.start_clues)/calc.total_clues*100) as team_percentage
FROM
    (SELECT log1.user_id, log1.team_id, log1.clues_found as start_clues, log2.clues_found as end_clues, log2.clues_to_find as total_clues FROM team_log log1
    JOIN
    (SELECT MIN(id) as start_id, MAX(id) as end_id FROM team_log GROUP BY user_id) ids
    ON ids.start_id = log1.id
    JOIN team_log log2 ON ids.end_id = log2.id) calc
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY team_id;
```

[And the SQL Fiddle-link...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f769/18/0)

Comment: I'll try this out. And check the best answer performance wise. Thanks for the help

Comment: I really like two things about this query.  1) Using MAX(id) will solve any problems with two entries with same date.  2) Group for start/end in one query really simplifies the rest of the joins.  It also makes the equation for percent really easy to see.

Comment: @Marty yours is a much simpler way to get the results as long as min(id) and max(id) can refer to the start and end dates correctly... :) As you can see there's no sqeuence between the dates, although i this sample data you get lucky. What if 14th was 3rd id for user team 1 ;) No offense..

Answer (score 1):

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ffc3/18)

```
SELECT `team_id`,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN b.`date` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE `clues_found` * 100 / `clues_to_find` END) -
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.`date` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE `clues_found` * 100 / `clues_to_find` END)) / 2
FROM `team_log` a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `team_id`, `user_id`, MAX(date) AS `date`
    FROM `team_log`
    GROUP BY `team_id`, `user_id`) b
  USING (`team_id`, `user_id`, `date`)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `team_id`, `user_id`, MIN(date) AS `date`
    FROM `team_log`
    GROUP BY `team_id`, `user_id`) c
  USING (`team_id`, `user_id`, `date`)
  GROUP BY `team_id`
```

Since you say there are always two team members, I've used `/2`. It would be slightly more complex for variable-sized teams.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that the clues_found can either increase or decrease. No guarantee that the highest number is the latest. Also won't SUM(clues_found) sum all the values for every row? For instance, wouldn't sum(clues_found) return 20 for user_id = 25?

Comment: ok... I totally misunderstood the question... understand it now... will give it another shot

Comment: @jribeiro "clues_found can either increase or decrease." How do you unfind a clue?

Comment: The answer might be considered invalid by an admin after. Admins validation. As this is a daily record it will be reflected later

Comment: This approach should be faster than @ebyrob's

Comment: I think @Marty McVry has us both beat on performance.  It's hard to get faster than one min/max group by user_id and two lookups by primary key.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit ugly, but should work:

```
select
   team_id,
   AVG(percentage_per_user) as team_percentage
from (select
  team_id,
  user_id,
  ((select clues_found from progress_tracker as x
      where x.user_id = m.user_id order by x.date desc limit 0, 1)
    - (select clues_found from progress_tracker as y
      where y.user_id = m.user_id order by y.date asc limit 0, 1))
  / MAX(clues_to_find)
  as percentage_per_user
from progress_tracker as m
group by team_id, user_id
) as userScore
group by team_id
order by team_percentage desc;
```

Note the inner query run by itself will yield your intermediate "per-user" result.

Comment: Thanks @ebyrob, it's a bit ugly yes but the results are spot on. Really apreciated the help!